# Service is unable to assume a role error - AWS Glue cloudformation creation with JDBC target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

```
Resources:
  GlueCrawlerRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - glue.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /service-role/
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: GlueAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Sid: kmsKeyAccess
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                 - 'kms:Encrypt'
                 - 'kms:Decrypt'
                 - 'kms:ReEncrypt*'
                 - 'kms:GenerateDataKey*'
                 - 'kms:DescribeKey'
                Resource: !Ref KmsKeyArn
              - Sid: logKmsKey
                Effect: Allow
                Action:
                 - 'logs:AssociateKmsKey'
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws-glue/:*'


GlueCrawler:
    Type: 'AWS::Glue::Crawler'
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}'
      Role: !GetAtt GlueCrawlerRole.Arn
      DatabaseName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-database'
      Targets:
        S3Targets:
          - Path: !Ref MyS3Bucket
        JdbcTargets: 
          - 
            ConnectionName: "XXXXXXX"
            Path: "ABCD/%"
        DatabaseName: "rds-xxxxx-abcd01-private-db"
        SchemaChangePolicy: 
          UpdateBehavior: "UPDATE_IN_DATABASE"
          DeleteBehavior: "DEPRECATE_IN_DATABASE"
        TablePrefix: "aurora_rds_"
```

<>
Service is unable to assume role arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:role/cua-enterprise-data-hub-dev-test-g-GlueCrawlerRole-1FB4KV7YGL1QB. Please verify role's TrustPolicy (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: bb1b60a5-3301-40de-81bf-ea78018cffa9)

Answer (score 1):

Your resources are **incorrect**. Instead of

```
Resource: 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws-glue/:*'
Resource: 'arn:aws:glue:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*'
```

there should be (**missing** `!Sub`):

```
Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:log-group:/aws-glue/:*'
Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:glue:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*'
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but initially, I had provided Resource: '*'. But it was still failing with the error "Service is unable to assume role arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/cua-enterprise-data-hub-dev-test-g-GlueCrawlerRole-1FB4KV7YGL1QB. Please verify role's TrustPolicy (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: bb1b60a5-3301-40de-81bf-ea78018cffa9)"

Comment: @Sou You need to provide full template. Where and how do you use the `GlueCrawlerRole`?

Comment: Updated in the initial Question

Comment: @Sou The code seems fine. Are you sure this is the correct code and its fully representative of your real code? Also, is it cralwer that fails or glue job?

Comment: Crawler gets failed because of the assumeRole error. Also, I would like to mention that in this question I have added iam:PassRole. In my actual code, that piece is not present. Do you think adding iam:PassRole would resolve this issue?

Comment: @Sou I don't know what is your factual code and how it relates to your question. Can you please ensure that your question accurately represents your real code. There is nothing wrong with trust relationship in your role.

Comment: I have now provided the actual code. Kindly check if this is OK. This code gets failed with the error I have already provided.

Comment: @Sou What happens if you manually in AWS console try to reproduce your role and cralwer? It also does not work?

Comment: @Sou  I don't know what could be wrong. Your template seems fine. Are you sure that it is crawler that's failing, not job with the same role?

Comment: yeah, am sure its crawler which is failing. Even am not sure what's wrong :)

Comment: @Sou Although very late the issue might be the name of the role, it has to start with "AWSGlueServiceRole" as written here step 6.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/create-an-iam-role.html

Comment: @Em.C thanks for replying. This was sorted already long time back. Appreciate

Comment: @Sou No problem. If the answer helped, its [acceptance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Summary

- Add dependency to the resource and the role.
- The resource should depend on the role.

### Background

- I had a similar problem. This is my error message in the CloudFormation.

```
Service is unable to assume role arn:aws:iam::123412341234:role/ETL-ROLE-GLUE. Please verify role's TrustPolicy (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException; Request ID: 60245469-592f-4f41-9b91-1dc786a72e47; Proxy: null)
```

- I realized that the role may not be created when the crawler is made. So, this is my CDK code change I made.

```
  private createCrawlersAppFlow() {
    // < snip >
    const crawlerSet = this.createCrawler({
      roleName: this.roleGlue.name,  // <=== Note that we are using the role's name only
      // < snip >>
      prefix: this.prefix,
    });
    crawlerSet.crawler.node.addDependency(this.roleGlue.role);  // <=== added in to force resource creation dependency
    return crawlerSet;
  }
```

- Then the problem is gone. You might want to add [CloudFormation level resource dependency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-dependson.html).